# Is it always a bad idea to extend JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, composition

When developing Java Swing GUIs, is it always a bad idea to extend JFrame? And what about JPanel, or other JComponents? Also, what makes it bad?

Comment: "what makes it bad?"  Why do you think it's bad?

Comment: Who said it's a bad idea?  As far as I can tell, `JPanel` is *expected* to be extended from for custom components.

Comment: What about JFrame? I honestly don't know what makes it bad. People just make claims that it's bad without giving any reasoning behind it. I'm curious as to what's actually wrong with it.

Comment: @Bob Who are those people?  I've never heard that.

Comment: @mKorbel I am very curious to know why it is a bad idea

Comment: @Maxpm JPanel (worse JFrame) are extended way more often than they should be, almost always for the false reasons.. because how often do you really create a new general swing component for your application? If it doesn't make sense to use your newly created `NewFrame` in other programs it shouldn't be using inheritance. Composition makes life much easier.

Comment: @prajeesh kumar answer to this question must be correct and wrotten in English (there is my dis_advantage) language

Answer (score 6):

Usually it's a rule of thumb to only subclass if you need to customize the Swing component.

Comment: @KirkWoll, As in add behavior or LaF not native to the component, or see [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/customize?s=t).

Comment: everything is described `java Composition versus Inheritance`

Comment: @mKorbel  Good you added the key term 'Composition versus Inheritance', since that is what it comes down to.

Comment: @KirkWoll Usually that would be a necessary override of at least one method.