# Access restriction: The type JLabel is not accessible due to restriction on required library C: \Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

when i whats use extends JFrame in my class this error display:
Access restriction: The type JLabel is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:  \Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\rt.jar

what should i do?

Comment: A tip for once you've solved the immediate problem:  *"i whats use extends JFrame"*  Don't extend `JFrame`, it is a poor practice.  Just use an instance of a standard `JFrame`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - sorry for the intrusion, didn't know if a new question was appropriate. Why is it poor practise? Closest I could find is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742018/is-it-always-a-bad-idea-to-extend-jframe which doesn't give much in the definitive.

Comment: @Gorb *"doesn't give much in the definitive."* From the accepted answer.  *"only subclass if you need to **customize** the Swing component."*  And by 'customize' a programmer would read `@Override` somewhere in the new class definition.  The words 'customize' does not just mean change the look and feel or the icon or transparency of a frame, but instead to change the standard `JFrame` methods.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see it was accepted. That makes sense regardless - your clarification about `@Override` is appreciated.